# Application_Start ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, application-lifecycle, application-start, httpapplication

If get this from the Microsoft official [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473(v=VS.100).aspx):

> The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance.

I was sure that Application_Start was related to the HttpApplication, here [this guy explains](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/05/HttpApplication-instances.aspx) why I was wrong.
Which object/entity is related to the Application_Start event?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the documentation says, the events are linked to the lifetime of the [application domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx), which in practice means the app pool which the application is running in. Application_Start will fire again if the app pool is recycled for any reason - a change to web.config, for example.