# Second instance of MvcApplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I am trying to implement MembershipProvider with IoC described in this article: http://bugsquash.blogspot.cz/2010/11/windsor-managed-membershipproviders.html

But I have some problems with my MvcApplication class which is implementing IContainerAccessor. But when I am trying to access the container by following code in MyMembershipProvider the container is null reference.

```
(HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor).Container
```

I found that there is second instance of MvcApplication which method Application_Start() was not called. Therefore no instance was set to Container property.

Why there is second instance of MvcApplication class? I thought that there will be only one instance. And how come that Application_Start() was not called?

I am using .net4 and mvc3.

Comment: Your container is probably not static. See http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=233

Comment: I believe it should not be static if there will be only one instance of MvcApplication class.

Comment: I found information about instances of HttpApplication class and you are right. It mast be static. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found answer. My question is related to this one [Application_Start ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093026/application-start-asp-net)

And informations about instances of HttpApplication class is in this blog post http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/05/HttpApplication-instances.aspx which is answer I was looking for.